# How can I get intent value in condition of IBM Watson Assistance user interface?

Tags: watson-conversation

In the section of **If bot recognizes** I can say `intents[1].confidence > 0.4` but I can't know what is actually that intent, So is there a way to get that?

I can get all intents type and confidence in the **Respond** section with `<? intents ?>` object but it does not help in **If bot recognizes** section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the intent by just using `intents[1].intent`. Just be aware that you are requesting the second choice, not the first. The first one would be `intents[0]`.

If you have a complex tree you want to parse, looking for this each time can be an issue. So there are two approaches.

1. Load a context variable with the intent name, and check for that. This adds overhead in your object store, but allows you to be more dynamic.
2. If it is the second choice you want, and you don't care about the first choice: On your main execution node, set `intents[0].intent = intents[1].intent` and the same for `confidence`. This will allow the normal lookup to take over.

There is more details on the objects in Watson Assistant here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#access-intent

Answer (score 0):

I get the value of confidence with filter like this:

Example:

```
    <? intents.filter("x", "x.intent == 'name_of_intent'").![confidence].get(0) ?>
```

Explanation:

1. Get the array of intents: `intents.filter("x", "x.intent == 'name_of_intent'")`, where "x" is a temporary variable, and `name_of_intent` is the intent that you want to get.
2. Then, you get back another array. Then to get the confidence value you have to `![confidence].get(0)`. And that's all.

The method explain:
`JSONArray.filter(temp, "temp.property operator comparison_value")`

So.. Like in docs:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods